# Finding gap within int valued column

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Hello In my 2008 SQL Server I have a column `sitting` which contains `int` values as following

`0,1,2,4,5` I want `3`

`1,2,3,5,6,7,8` I want `0`

`0,1,2,3,6,7,8` I want `4`

`0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` I want `9`

And what I'm trying to achieve here is to find the `gap` between given numbers. I tried following code that works well for me but I was thinking that it is pretty hard-coded so I wanted to know if there isn't any simplier way to achieve that e.g. `SQL query`?

The column must always start with `0` so when no results are found I need to put `0` first.

If there is no gap I need to just continue and add max value + 1 .

```
object resultSeat = "";
string querySeat = "SELECT ID_K FROM klient WHERE sitting=@sitting AND (event=@event";
for (int a = 0; a < ConnectedEvents.Count(); a++)
{
    querySeat += " OR event='" + ConnectedEvents[a] + "'";
}
querySeat += ")";
for (int i = 0; i <= resultKlimax; i++)
{

   SqlCommand comQuerySeat = new SqlCommand(querySeat,conn);
   comQuerySeat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sitting",i);
   comQuerySeat.Parameters.AddWithValue("@event", zevent.Text);

   conn.Open();
   resultSeat = comQuerySeat.ExecuteScalar();
   conn.Close();

   if ((resultSeat == null) || (resultSeat == DBNull.Value)) 
         break;

      txt_sitting.Text = (i+1).ToString();
    }

}
if (txt_sitting.Text == "") txt_sitting.Text = "0";
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you get all rows, sort by sitting.
Then assume starting at 1, loop until number of rows returned
If sitting does not equal loop count, AHA

Comment: What would you want the output to be if you had "1,2,3,6,7,8"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff `0` when it is `0,1,2,3,6,7,8` I want `4`, when it is `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` I want `9`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, just use the `lag()` function to find the next record after a gap:

```
select s.intcol
from (select s.intcol, lag(intcol) over (order by intcol) as prevval
      from sitting s
     ) s
where prevval <> intcol - 1;
```

You an do the same thing with a correlated subquery.

EDIT:

To get `4`, use `lead()` instead and add 1:

```
select s.intcol + 1
from (select s.intcol, lead(intcol) over (order by intcol) as nextval
      from sitting s
     ) s
where nextval <> s.intcol + 1;
```

To do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select s.intcol + 1
from (select s.intcol,
             (select top 1 s2.intcol
              from sitting s2
              where s2.intcol > s.intcol
              order by s2.intcol
             ) as nextval
      from sitting s
     ) s
where nextval <> s.intcol + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but I also use 2012 but need to improve it also for 2008 SQL Server. Forget to add that to my question, sorry .

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Select TOP 1 ISNULL(NextID, (Select MAX(ID) + 1 from Table)) from
(Select ID, Row_Number() OVER (Order by ID) NextID from Table) a
where ID <> NextID
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID FROM MyTable", "connection string here"))
{
    var table = new DataTable();

    adapter.Fill(table);

    var ids = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<int>("ID")).ToArray();
    var minId = ids.Min();
    var maxId = ids.Max();
    var missingIds = Enumerable.Range(minId, maxId - minId + 1).Except(ids);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:
A record with a 'sitting' value X for which there is no record that has a 'sitting' value of X + 1

This can be expressed as a SQL query:

```
SELECT sitting + 1
FROM   klient 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT sitting
               FROM   klient AS klientInner
               WHERE  klientInner.sitting = klient.sitting + 1
           )
```

This retrieves all gaps. If you just want to know the first gap and you want to handle the case that there are no records at all, you can do the following

```
SELECT ISNULL(MIN(sitting + 1), 0)
FROM   ...
       ...
```

Note: I don't know what the performance is if there are millions of records. It should be wise to review this before using this query.

---

I just noticed that this solution does not cover the case: `1,2,3,5,6,7,8` should return `0`.
You could just check this with a separate query.